# Headers already sent error

Tags: php, errors

I tried to install a wordpress 6.3 site with php 8.1 which is standard in ubuntu 22.04.
I could install it but was unable to install or delete plugins.

Always got errors about not possible headers modified.

Can anyone confirm that wordpress 6.3 runs with php 8.1

This is what I got after fresh installation.

[image]

Here the errors I get in google chrome.

[image]

Here the apache log

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function send_origin_headers() in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:25\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 25', referer: https://test.1w.at/wp-admin/

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function main() on null in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/functions.php:1335\nStack trace:\n#0 /_www/test.1w.at/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()\n#1 /_www/test.1w.at/index.php(17): require('...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335'

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_get_server_info(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, null given in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php:4165\nStack trace:\n#0 /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php(4165): mysqli_get_server_info()\n#1 /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php(4153): wpdb->db_server_info()\n#2 /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php(4072): wpdb->db_version()\n#3 /_www/test.1w.at/wp-admin/setup-config.php(395): wpdb->has_cap()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /_www/test.1w.at/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 4165', referer: https://test.1w.at/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1&language=de_DE_formal
```

Comment: 6.3 should run on 8.1 fine? I was certainly running the early 6.3 alphas on php 8.1 fine (but then upgraded to 8.2).

Comment: The `Headers already modified` error indicates that something—a theme, a plugin, or WP Core—has sent data to the browser before PHP is trying to set a header. Often this is due to whitespace after a closing PHP tag `?>`. Are you using one of WordPress's default themes (ie, `twenty____`)? Did you start to see the error after activating a plugin?

Comment: Can you add the exact and complete error messages that you got, including file paths, stack traces, etc? It's difficult to give any useful info without more details.

Comment: Just installed it again and updated my previous post.

Comment: That doesn't really tell us what's going wrong sorry. Can you see errors in your browser's debug console or network tab? Are files failing to load, getting malformed, etc.? Does the page view source look OK? I assume you got through the installation steps OK to get this far? Are you still getting the headers modified error in your server logs? Does the login page and the main site look OK?

Comment: Just posted another screenshot. BTW you can test it by callung https://test.1w.at. Its online

Comment: I installed WP serveral times with different errors. One time front end is ok, but in backend can not install plugins, next time cant login to backend, next tie distorted front end, and so on ...

Comment: I confirm wordpress 6.3 runs with php 8.1 with no problem.
delete whole wordpress files and folders. install it again and put php on 8.1. last month i had kinda this problem but website didn't show any thing.

Comment: I was going to say we can't, because we can't login, but it looks like that's actually your 403 error page (!). If you view source you'll see that you have a second doctype on line 121. It looks like your site is sending the 403 error page but then not stopping with die() and carrying on and trying to render an admin page.

Comment: wp_die() supports continuing, if you pass argument exit=>false, but that shouldn't happen. Skimming the code you ought to hit auth_redirect() rather than a 403 in the admin site anyway. Something very odd is happening. It looks like you have active plugins: can you try moving their folders out of the way to deactivate them to see if this goes away?

Comment: In particular is anything adding filters on anything related to wp_die, or overriding pluggable functions for wp_die or its handlers.

Comment: No plugins, original 2023 theme, and fresh install from wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz and gtar -xzvf latest.tar.gz on Ubuntu 22.04.3 with PHP 8.1.22 (cli) (built: Aug 14 2023 05:32:33). If I switch to php 7.4 everything runs smootly.